# Apollo Server, measure of execution time

Tags: apollo-server

Is there a way to measure the execution time of a query or a mutation?

I was thinking on something like:

```
import measurePlugin from 'some-plugin'

const server = new ApolloServer({
  resolvers,
  typeDefs,
  dataSources,
  context,
  plugins: [
    measurePlugin)
  ]
});
```

I don't know if existe a plugin for that or Apollo Server has an option for that.

I just want to console.log out the time while a query/mutation is called and the resolvers ends the execution.

Comment: Did you got any luck here?

Comment: @ShivamSahil no, I have a custom helper for that but I have to use it on each resolver... I wanted a global solution. each resolver is only a: `try { startMeasure; callRealFunction; endMeasureSuccess } catch((e) => { endMeasureError; return e}`